# Use of an array of strings to have conditions of which data to copy in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am doing a code where you decide which parameters to include in my general report. I need to change my code when a parameters is to be reomved or added.

When a change is done, I need to change which report to open and copy the formatted table from. What I want my code to do is to ask the user for the parameters they want to include and store them in some array (maybe) and the following code would have conditions to check if the string array has the word for the parameter.

Here I am pasting an idea but I am not sure if this is the more efficient way.

```
Dim parameters() As String
'Input box for size of array*
redim parameters(size)

'Input box for p1, p2, ... pn
parameters = { p_1, p_2, ... p_n}  ' I am not really sure about this part

For i = 1 To size
    If LCase(parameters(i)) = "parameter_name1" Then 
        'Copy the table of paramater_name1 report
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To size
    If LCase(parameters(i)) = "parameter_name2" Then 
        'Copy the table of paramater_name2 report
        Exit For
    End If
Next i  

...
```

Is there a more concrete (and less iterative) way to find if the input value is in the array? As you can see I am checking each object in the array.

Any kind of help is welcome.

Comment: there is no question in your speech, only wants.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me or finish my code for me site.  Please explain the problem with the existing code and ask a specific question about what the code is doing that is in error.  Not "How do I get from here to where I want?"

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I am only looking for a way to check if there is a specific string in the array without using a For loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not clear which VBA application is your context (i.e. you could use `Application.Match` in Excel-VBA), you can achieve this with the help of a `Scripting.Dictionary` object, where you put your parameter names as keys, then check with `Dictionary.Exists` method. You then achieve two benefits:

- Easy search without loop
- Fast search

.

```
Sub UsingADictionary()
    Dim D As Object: Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    D.CompareMode = TextCompare ' <-- If you want to ignore case in param names

    ' dummy statement to insert keys. Values will be 0, don't care
    D("p_1") = D("p_2") + D("p_3") + D("p_4") + D("p_5")  '...

    If D.Exists("p_2") Then
      Debug.Print "p_2 exists"
      ' ... do something for p_2
    Else
      Debug.Print "p_2 does not exist"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Now that you specified Excel and `Application.Match`, it can work this way. Notice that your array for search should be declared as variant, not as a typed array such as

```
Sub UsingMatch()
  Dim parameters
  parameters = Array("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee")

  If Not IsError(Application.Match("a", parameters, 0)) Then
    Debug.Print "aa found"
  Else
    Debug.Print "aa Not found"
  End If
End Sub
```

Note that `Match` is not case sensitive.

Comment: I wanted to try this, but i did not get this part so I could not fit it in my code.

`D("p_1") = D("p_2") + D("p_3") + D("p_4") + D("p_5")`

I am using Excel VBA so maybe `application.match` would work as you stated.

Comment: @J.Bringas `application.match` is specific to Excel. You did not specify that you are using Excel. Are you? If so you should add the `excel` and `excel-vba` tags.

Comment: @J.Bringas see the last part for using `Match`. Besides, I dont understand what you did not "get" from the dictionary part. The comment above that line clearly states what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can search an array by joining it to a string and search the string, here is an example of how it works:

```
Sub SearchArray()
    Dim MyArr As Variant
    MyArr = Array("Hello", "World", "These", "Are", "Seperate", "Array", "Values")
    If InStr(1, "|" & Join(MyArr, "|") & "|", "|These|") > 0 Then MsgBox "Found These"
    If InStr(1, "|" & Join(MyArr, "|") & "|", "|NotInArray|") > 0 Then MsgBox "Found NotInArray"
End Sub
```

We join the array to a single string using a pipe | as a delimiter, we then top and tail the string with a | so that we can search for our string with a pipe on either side, we do this to stop it returning a false positive if our search term exists in part in another value.

Once we have our string, we use instr to determine the starting char of our search term, if it is not found it will simply be zero, a simple test to see if the result is >0 will determine if the value you are looking for is present in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for u

```
For i=lbound(parameters) to ubound(parameters)
  Select Case Lcase(parameters(i))
    Case "parameter name1"
      Set tbl= ws.ListObjects(tablename)
  End Select
  'Copy tablecontents
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfect for my purpose, I'd never heard of _lbound_ nor _ubound_ but it is good to learn this stuff.